# SLA for Airflow DAG with schedule frequency - once

Tags: airflow

I am trying to add in SLA for the DAG/individual tasks which have a schedule frequency once. Essentially, I have a template DAG(schedule frequency once) which gets triggered by another DAG on a weekly schedule. Adding `'sla': timedelta(seconds=12)` to these template DAGs has no effect. I can add it to all the other DAGs and it works okay. Is there a way to add SLAs to the DAGs with a schedule frequency @once?

Comment: I would advice to add some code into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help plus reduce the chances of having your question flagged and closed.